# Why type inference works when applying currying in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have some generic method that looks like the following.

With defining the method this way, Scala cannot infer the types A and B for some reason.

```
  def someMethod[A <: UpperBoundA, B <: UpperBoundB](m: Map[A, B], condition: A => Boolean): Option[B] = 
    m.filterKeys(condition).headOption.map(_._2)
```

But when transforming the method as below by applying currying, Scala manages to correctly infer the types.

```
  def someMethod[A <: UpperBoundA, B <: UpperBoundB](m: Map[A, B])(condition: A => Boolean): Option[B] = 
    m.filterKeys(condition).headOption.map(_._2)
```

Here is how the methods all called

```
someMethod(m, _.someField == "aaa") // not working for some reason
someMethod[Key, Value](m, _.id == "aaa") // working
someMethod(m)(_.someField == "aaa") // working(with currying)
```

Why is that?

Comment: removed unnecessary bits

Comment: can you mention the way you are calling these functions?

Comment: @AnandSai I have added how the methods are called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of first case `someMethod(m, _.someField == "aaa")`, each argument in the function as equal by its importance, but if inference would work and you wrote `someMethod(m, _.someField == "aaa")`, then compiler treats it as `(x$1) => x$1.someField.$eq$eq("aaa")`.`x$1` can be A or any subtype of A. In that case, if you change the order of arguments, inference might change or might not work at all and this will make the inference complex for compiler to do as it has to scan the definition multiple times.

In the second case, `someMethod[Key, Value](m, _.id == "aaa")`, the compiler already knows that A is a type of Key and B is a type of Value and hence it compiles

As far as the third case is concerned `someMethod(m)(_.someField == "aaa")`, Compiler needs to infer type when you already wrote someMethod(m) because this is a partial application. So now, when the type is inferred, it can continue and apply (f) to it.

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So the reason for the first case not working is that too complex(time-consuming) for the compiler(current version) to infer the multiple types, whereas the last case works because the compiler just needs to infer a single type(argument) at a time?

Comment: @d-_-b What matters is not whether it's one type parameter or many; the actual limitation is stated in jwvh's answer.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler can't use the inference of one parameter to help resolve another unless those parameters are in different parameter groups.

It's the same with parameter values.

```
def f(x:Int = 4, y:Int = x) :Int = x*y  //Error: not found: value x
def f(x:Int = 4)(y:Int = x) :Int = x*y  //OK, 2 default values
```

The compiler resolves the 1st parameter group before moving to the 2nd, and the information obtained from the 1st is available to the 2nd.

Answer (score 3):

Type inference flows left-to-right *from parameter list to parameter list*. Type inference *within* a parameter list happens at the same time for all parameters.